# Fluid causing ripples against smooth glass surface

Tags: animation, mesh, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to achieve a "smooth" pour of liquid into this glass. However, after a while of tinkering (I'm a beginner), the fluid just won't be smooth against the glass: it keeps showing these odd ripples, even though the mesh is technically smooth.

You can see a final render [here](https://youtu.be/iLl2cslOqSc)

I'll also attach the [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_WcR0NOFCsiROlrthCJmV4OzThljEBQ/view?usp=sharing) - maybe somebody understands the science of this better than I do.

P.S. I've tried solving it by using a boolean operation but this results in weird artifacts coming up that don't look too good.

Comment: did you try to increase the resolution?

Comment: I've taken it as high as 128 @Chris